# unit testing angular service, beforeEach inject doesn't execute

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to write unit tests for an angular service with jasmine/karma. I have a similar service test, which works just fine. But this one has some additional dependencies, is in a different module and just doesn't find the service with the inject.

The service looks something like this. `bService` is in the same module, but `commonFactory` and `commonService` are in another module, say `commonModule`.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     angular
         .module('myService')
         .service('aService', aService);

     aService.$inject = [
         'commonFactory',
         'commonService'
         'bService'
     ];

     function aService (
         commonFactory,
         commonService,
         bService
     ) {

     };

     return {
         codeIWantToTest: CodeIWantToTest;
     }

     function CodeIWantToTest () {
          console.log('surprise!');
     }
})();
```

My jasmine test looks like:

```
describe('myService.aService', function () {
    'use strict';
    var aService;
    // I tried adding beforeEach(module('commonModule')); too, but that didn't do anything
    beforeEach(module('myService'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        inject(function(_aService_) {
            console.log('getting aService');
            aService = _aService_;
        });
    }); 

    it('tests my service is defined', function() {
        expect(myService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

This test fails. `myService` isn't defined and the `console.log` in the inject function doesn't ever fire. My `karma.conf.js` basically lists the dependencies in the order that they're injected into the service, then adds the service then the test.

What would cause the inject to not grab the service? What am I missing? I mentioned I have a similar test for `commonService` and it works just fine. So I'm baffled.

Comment: You don't typically test services but the result of the service in a controller.

Comment: Edited code, added missing `'` on `bService`. In case it wasn't an issue just from copying to SO.

Comment: it's missing the `_` at the end of `aService =_aService_` too.

Comment: @MatthewGreen You don't typically test them like this? Does that mean it just won't work? I need to do it at a higher level?

Comment: @MatthewGreen Where did you get this from? Actually it is the opposite; in unit tests you test separate units in isolation, so there are fewer moving parts and red test unambiguously indicates which unit was failed. Hence the name, unit test.

Comment: @estus [Angular themselves don't provide guidance on testing services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing). You should test things in isolation but services are like private functions in Java, you should only be testing the contract or outcome of a function but not the private or hidden implementation details.

Comment: @MatthewGreen But they do have guidance|https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#! (at the very bottom). This is what I was following. I tried it this way too, with the `$injector` and still no dice.

Comment: @MatthewGreen The thing you're describing is functional test. If a method is private, it still can (and should) be reflected. If it is unreachable for spying/mocking, then the design is bad. But one of the main benefits of Angular DI is that every dependency can be spied or mocked. There's more than one way to test things, but usually the one gets rock solid tests when having everything covered by both unit and functional/integration/e2e tests.

Comment: @shelbydz You still have `aService = _aService` in your code. Failed test should produce an error message that explains why it was failed. If you don't have this message, this is possibly due to the fact that PhantomJS swallows errors in `beforeEach`, this is a common problem. Try to move `inject` to `it` block` or switch to Chrome launcher in Karma.

Comment: Even with that example it doesn't seem to be recommended practice. Or why leave it off of the testing page? Either a serious oversight or they think there is much better ways to do your testing that don't involve testing the service explicitly.

Comment: @estus That's just a typo in my example. It's correct in the actual test: `aService = _aService_`

Comment: The rest of the comment is still actual. There should be error message and it should be listed in the question on order to receive the answer. There are several reasons why this may fail, the obvious one is that `angular.module('myService')` requires this file to be loaded it spec AND to load the file that has `angular.module('myService', [...])` before. The question misses this part.

Comment: @estus I moved the inject into the `it` block. Same results. I wrapped the inject in a try catch, dumped out the error and got this LONG string. The inject is failing and causing the test to bail. I assume it's because it can't find `_aService_` ?

Comment: Please, always post this 'long string', the question is incomplete without it. `inject(...)` call bootstraps the app, so this can be caused by any bootstrap problem.

Comment: Here's the error: http://pastebin.com/Ka3XB6rE

Comment: The first thing is that it should be posted in the question, because it is relevant. The second thing is that it is useless because there's no error message, only call stack. The thing I've told above is still applicable. If you're using PhantomJS, I suggest to switch to Chrome, because PhantomJS swallows error messages. Don't catch the error. It will appear in test report.

Comment: This is all within a docker container. I need to talk to a teammate about getting chrome added into it. I'll repost once I have more data. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another dev on my team found the solution and I wanted to post it as an answer for the future people. I had a feeling it was a dependency problem, and it was. While we were loading all of the JS stuff correctly, the template that the component uses was loading another js dependency. So to fix this for jasmine, we had two different solutions:

at the top of the component test file, we could add:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.constant('myMissingDependency', {
            // do things to load the dependency here
            });
    });
});
```

In our case it was a translation library

The other solution was to add a 'shim' file into the unit test directory and load it with karma.config.js ahead of the tests. That looked like:

```
(function() {
    angular
        .module('MyService')
        .constant('myMissingDependency', Object.freeze({
            // things to load the dependency
        }));
})();
```

I wasn't able to switch to Chrome because we're using Docker and I couldn't get the tests to run locally to run Chrome. So adding a second set of eyes to this was what I needed.