# AngularJS doesn't consider mocked service in jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking

I am trying to unit test an AngularJS service using Jasmine and Karma. The following is a minimal (obfuscated) representation of my code:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app.mock', []);

var MyHelper = function(pollHelper) {
  var poller = pollHelper.getInstance();
};

var PollHelper = function() {
  var service = this;
  service.getInstance = function() {}
};

angular.module('app')
  .service('myHelper', MyHelper)
  .service('pollHelper', PollHelper);

angular.module('app.mock')
  .service('pollHelperMock', function() {
    var methods = ['getInstance'],
      pollHelper = jasmine.createSpyObj('pollHelperMock', methods);
    return pollHelper;
  });

describe('MyHelper', function() {
  var pollHelper, myHelper, $rootScope;
  pollHelper = jasmine.createSpy('pollHelper');
  beforeEach(module('app.mock'));

  beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
    console.log('prints 1'); // Prints on console

    $provide.service('pollHelper', function() {
      return pollHelper;
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(
    inject(
      function(_pollHelperMock_, _myHelper_, _$rootScope_) {
        console.log('prints 2'); // Doesn't print anything

        pollHelper.and.callFake(_pollHelperMock_);
        angular.extend(pollHelper, _pollHelperMock_);
        myHelper = _myHelper_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
      }));

  describe('Initialization', function() {
    it('Gets poller instance', function() {
      $rootScope.$apply();
    });
  });
});


/// Code for Jasmine test executor
(function() {
  var env = jasmine.getEnv();
  env.addReporter(new jasmine.HtmlReporter());
  env.execute();
}());
```

```css
#HTMLReporter #jasmine_content,#TrivialReporter #jasmine_content{position:fixed;right:100%}body{background-color:#eee;padding:0;margin:5px;overflow-y:scroll}#HTMLReporter{font-size:11px;font-family:Monaco,"Lucida Console",monospace;line-height:14px;color:#333}#HTMLReporter a{text-decoration:none}#HTMLReporter a:hover{text-decoration:underline}#HTMLReporter h1,#HTMLReporter h2,#HTMLReporter h3,#HTMLReporter h4,#HTMLReporter h5,#HTMLReporter h6,#HTMLReporter p{margin:0;line-height:14px}#HTMLReporter .alert .bar,#HTMLReporter .banner,#HTMLReporter .resultMessage,#HTMLReporter .specDetail .description,#HTMLReporter .stackTrace,#HTMLReporter .summary,#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary{padding-left:9px;padding-right:9px}#HTMLReporter .version{color:#aaa}#HTMLReporter .banner{margin-top:14px}#HTMLReporter .duration{color:#aaa;float:right}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary{overflow:hidden;margin:14px 0}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li{display:block;float:left;height:7px;width:14px;margin-bottom:7px;font-size:16px}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.passed,#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.skipped{font-size:14px}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.passed:before{color:#5e7d00;content:"\02022"}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.failed{line-height:9px}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.failed:before{color:#b03911;content:"x";font-weight:700;margin-left:-1px}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.skipped:before{color:#bababa;content:"\02022"}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.pending{line-height:11px}#HTMLReporter .symbolSummary li.pending:before{color:#aaa;content:"-"}#HTMLReporter .exceptions{color:#fff;float:right;margin-top:5px;margin-right:5px}#HTMLReporter .results,#HTMLReporter .summary{margin-top:14px}#HTMLReporter .bar{line-height:28px;font-size:14px;display:block;color:#eee}#HTMLReporter #details,#HTMLReporter.showDetails .summary{display:none}#HTMLReporter .runningAlert{background-color:#666}#HTMLReporter .skippedAlert{background-color:#aaa}#HTMLReporter .skippedAlert:first-child{background-color:#333}#HTMLReporter .skippedAlert:hover{color:#fff;text-decoration:underline}#HTMLReporter .passingAlert{background-color:#a6b779}#HTMLReporter .passingAlert:first-child{background-color:#5e7d00}#HTMLReporter .failingAlert{background-color:#cf867e}#HTMLReporter .failingAlert:first-child{background-color:#b03911}#HTMLReporter .resultsMenu,#HTMLReporter .resultsMenu a{background-color:#fff;color:#333}#HTMLReporter.showDetails .summaryMenuItem{font-weight:400;text-decoration:inherit}#HTMLReporter .summaryMenuItem,#HTMLReporter.showDetails .detailsMenuItem{font-weight:700;text-decoration:underline}#HTMLReporter.showDetails .summaryMenuItem:hover{text-decoration:underline}#HTMLReporter .resultMessage span.result,#HTMLReporter.showDetails #details{display:block}#HTMLReporter .summary .specSummary,#HTMLReporter .summary .suite .suite{margin-left:14px}#HTMLReporter .summary .specSummary.passed a{color:#5e7d00}#HTMLReporter .summary .specSummary.failed a{color:#b03911}#HTMLReporter .description+.suite{margin-top:0}#HTMLReporter .suite{margin-top:14px}#HTMLReporter .suite a{color:#333}#HTMLReporter #details .specDetail{margin-bottom:28px}#HTMLReporter #details .specDetail .description{display:block;color:#fff;background-color:#b03911}#HTMLReporter .resultMessage{padding-top:14px;color:#333}#HTMLReporter .stackTrace{margin:5px 0 0;max-height:224px;overflow:auto;line-height:18px;color:#666;border:1px solid #ddd;background:#fff;white-space:pre}#TrivialReporter{padding:8px 13px;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;overflow-y:scroll;background-color:#fff;font-family:"Helvetica Neue Light","Lucida Grande",Calibri,Arial,sans-serif}#TrivialReporter a,#TrivialReporter a:visited{color:#303}#TrivialReporter a:active,#TrivialReporter a:hover{color:#00f}#TrivialReporter .run_spec{float:right;padding-right:5px;font-size:.8em;text-decoration:none}#TrivialReporter .banner{color:#303;background-color:#fef;padding:5px}#TrivialReporter .logo{float:left;font-size:1.1em;padding-left:5px}#TrivialReporter .logo .version{font-size:.6em;padding-left:1em}#TrivialReporter .runner.running{background-color:#ff0}#TrivialReporter .options{text-align:right;font-size:.8em}#TrivialReporter .suite{border:1px outset gray;margin:5px 0;padding-left:1em}#TrivialReporter .suite .suite{margin:5px}#TrivialReporter .suite.passed{background-color:#dfd}#TrivialReporter .suite.failed{background-color:#fdd}#TrivialReporter .spec{margin:5px;padding-left:1em;clear:both}#TrivialReporter .spec.failed,#TrivialReporter .spec.passed,#TrivialReporter .spec.skipped{padding-bottom:5px;border:1px solid gray}#TrivialReporter .spec.failed{background-color:#fbb;border-color:red}#TrivialReporter .spec.passed{background-color:#bfb;border-color:green}#TrivialReporter .spec.skipped{background-color:#bbb}#TrivialReporter .messages{border-left:1px dashed gray;padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em}#TrivialReporter .passed{background-color:#cfc;display:none}#TrivialReporter .failed{background-color:#fbb}#TrivialReporter .skipped{color:#777;background-color:#eee;display:none}#TrivialReporter .resultMessage span.result{display:block;line-height:2em;color:#000}#TrivialReporter .resultMessage .mismatch{color:#000}#TrivialReporter .stackTrace{white-space:pre;font-size:.8em;margin-left:10px;max-height:5em;overflow:auto;border:1px inset red;padding:1em;background:#eef}#TrivialReporter .finished-at{padding-left:1em;font-size:.6em}#TrivialReporter.show-passed .passed,#TrivialReporter.show-skipped .skipped{display:block}#TrivialReporter .runner{border:1px solid gray;display:block;margin:5px 0;padding:2px 0 2px 10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

The problem is that as soon as I try to execute the `my-helper.spec.js`, it throws an error which, in essence, says:

```
TypeError: pollHelper.getInstance is not a function
```

Moreover, the only the first `console.log` statement gets printed, not the second one, which makes an impression that the `inject` function isn't being called at all.

How can I go about testing the service, where the `getInstance()` is called as soon as the module initializes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why several `beforeEach`'s? I'm not familiar with that notation, so first I'd suggest using `beforeEach(function() {/* contents from three different beforeEach's here */});`

Comment: @jsruok -- Just tried combining them all, still no luck.

Comment: This is something very strange. To mock some service all you need is:
$provide.factory('$mdDialog', () => myMock);

You use callFake, when you did not mock.

Comment: As you're using obfuscated code, it might be missing some details, say, some dependencies. This person needed a second set of eyes to find the missing dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896782/unit-testing-angular-service-beforeeach-inject-doesnt-execute

Comment: @PetrAveryanov -- The issue is that `pollHelper.getInstance()` this statement fails as AngularJS tries to instantiate the `myService` as soon as it loads the module. My problem is which approach do I use, so that it calls the `getInstance()` of the mocked dependency?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the problem in SO snippet. Please take a look. Hope it clarifies the issue.

Comment: Do you want to get it working or get it working in your way? Cause usually people do not put mocks in module, do not spy on service itself (spies on their methods), etc. etc.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov -- I just want to get it working, but cannot touch this line `poller = pollHelper.getInstance();`. This line should be there where it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

This we want to test:

```
angular.module('app', []);

var MyHelper = function(pollHelper) {
  var poller = pollHelper.getInstance();
  console.log('in my helper:' + poller);
};

var PollHelper = function() {
  var service = this;
  service.name = 'original helper';
  service.getInstance = function() { return 'original helper instance'}
};

angular.module('app')
  .service('myHelper', MyHelper)
  .service('pollHelper', PollHelper);
```

In test:

```
const pollHelperMock = {
  name: 'mock helper',
  getInstance: function() { return 'mock helper result'; }
}
beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
  $provide.service('pollHelper', function() {
     return pollHelperMock;
  });
}));

beforeEach(inject(function(pollHelper, myHelper) {
  console.log(pollHelper.name);
  console.log(pollHelper.getInstance());
}))
```

Output:

```
in my helper:mock helper result
mock helper
mock helper result
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution you offered creates the mock for `pollHelper` in the test file itself, which, kind of, solves the problem, but I would rather opt for creating it in a different file and use it here. I would like to wait more for someone to post an answer which helps me understand another approaches to solve this problem.